# when mouse is hover on a dropdown menu division on a page is shifted

Tags: html, css

I am trying to develop a website which contains dropdown menu and in the next division below menu there is a slider division but when mouse is hover on menu the submenu displays and the slider division is shifts down.

So can anyone suggest how I can accomplish the task
The code is as follows

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
#header{
    height: 90px;
}
#navigation{
    height: 30px;
    background-color: #0099FF;
    border: 1px solid #0099FF;
    border-radius: 10px;
    z-index:1000;
}
ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
ul li {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    padding-right: 40px;    
}
li ul {
    display: none;
}
ul li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
}
ul li a:hover {
    background: #00CCFF;
}
li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    z-index: 1000;
}
li:hover li {
    float: none;
}
li:hover a {
    background: #00CCFF;
}
li:hover li a:hover {
    background: #D2F5FF;
}
#drop-nav li ul li {
    border-top: 0px;
}
#clearmenu{
    clear: left;
}
#sliderandnews{
    height: 300px;
}
#slidermain{
    height: 300px;
    width: 65%;
    float: left;
}
#news{
    height: 300px;
    width: 33%;
    border: 2px solid #F0FFFF;
    border-radius: 20px;
    float: right;
    background-color: #F0FFFF;
}
.clear{
    height: 40px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header">
</div>
<div id="navigation">
    <ul id="drop-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Academic Programs</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">BBA</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">BCA</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">BE</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Faculties</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Admission</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Downloads</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div id="sliderandnews">
        <div id="slidermain">
            This section is changes its position on mousehover
        </div>
        <div id="news">
        </div>
    </div>          
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please, post some code so we can help you. You can check the http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to improve your chances to get your question answered

Comment: Have you tried it first? If so, please share the jsfiddle or plunker link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your elements are relative positioned. So, when the submenu appears, all elements below are shifted down. You can add absolute positioning to navigation bar, and determine its displacement from top using the `top` property in CSS. This allows you to eliminate `#header` (which has only the role to give a top margin).

```
#navigation{
    position:absolute;
    top:90px;
}
```

Similarly you can do with the `#sliderandnews` block. Since you've given an absolute positioning to navigation menu, navigation is removed from HTML elements flow inside the page. To compensate this, you have to add a proper top margin to this element.

```
#sliderandnews{
    height: 300px;
    margin-top:190px;
}
```

And here's the final [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/165mk87q/3/).